# Neon Power Supply Voltage AC Measurement

Tags: power-supply, oscilloscope, high-voltage, pulse

So I was provided with a circuit which consists of a variable transformer connected to the main (essentially allows the input of the power supply to be controlled) and a Neon Power Supply (Has An Input Of: 120VAC 50/60Hz 0.9A, Output Of: 10kv 30mA). I have realized that once a set "minimum" voltage is set on the transformer (About 30VAC) high voltage pulses can be seen to appear on the oscilloscope display. These pulses however do not allow me to take measurements within the oscilloscope (such as frequency, pk-to-pk voltage and rms) due to the pulsing wave. I have been provided with a 100X:1000V CAT II probe manufactured by Tektronix but have been unsuccessful in obtaining any measurements of this power supply. I would like to know if there is something I'm missing (such as a setting on the oscope) or not doing correctly in order to measure the voltage of the power supply. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If your trying to measure 10kV, a 1000V probe is not sufficient

Comment: @laptop2d I don't believe I am reaching that 10kV ouput, the power supply requires 120VAC in order to then output the 10kV and I do not intend to exceed a 50VAC input provided by the variable transformer. I do however think the voltage output is in the kV so is there any other way I could measure the voltage?

Comment: [Are you the same person who asked this very similar question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447397/oscilloscope-high-voltage-and-current-measurements)

Comment: @JRE No but I did read the post and got excited to see that they were also using the same power supply however, I just want to measure the actual power supply

Comment: @custokumla You could use an HV resistor divider to bring the voltage range into the 1000V. As far as the probe goes, if the supply ever reached anything more than 1000V it's possible you've damaged the probe, and/or the scope. Check to make sure those are working first.

Comment: @laptop2d would the HV resistor divider vary from a regular voltage divider? I would need lots of resistors to build a divider that could in theory handle the 10kV

Comment: @custokumla You can't build an HV divider with regular through hole resistors, because the voltage could jump over the resistors, there is not a sufficient air gap between conductors.

Comment: @laptop2d What kind of resistors would I need to build a divider such as this?

Comment: search for high voltage resistor divider and find the one you need